# Way to mimic an Outlook application object with Outlook web

Tags: c#, webforms, outlook, outlook-web-app

I have a desktop application that launches an outlook client instance with information pre-filled.

```
var application = new Outlook.Application();
var mItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outLook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
mItem.To = "david@emailaddress.com";
mItem.Subject = "Hello";
mItem.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
mItem.HTMLBody = "Email body";
mItem.Display(false);
```

This way, the user can make changes before clicking Send in Outlook.

My goal is to mimic this in a webform.  Instead of launching desktop Oulook which can't/shouldn't happen due to security concerns, I would like to launch an Outlook Web window instead with information prefilled.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to do, but looks like the only solution is to use [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx).